# Apache2 not working in Ubuntu 14.04: won't restart, unknown job

Tags: apache2, lamp

I have the goal of starting and running a LAMP server with the goal of running a Drupal site, maybe Wordpress.

I haven't even gotten through the apache step.  I used `sudo apt-get install apache2-bin`, which was suggested by terminal.  Online recommends `sudo apt-get install apache2`, without the -bin.

```
$ apache2 -v 
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

`http://localhost/` yields; Unable to connect  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

`http://my-ip-address` (from icanhazip.com) just thinks and thinks, completes nothing, blank page

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
Apache2: unrecognised service
$ sudo apache2ctl graceful
sudo: apache2ctl: command not found
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
sudo: /etc/init.d/apache2: command not found
$ sudo start apache2
start: Unknown job: apache2
$ sudo restart apache2
restart; unknown job apache2
```

It seems installed, but not operational, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

Edit: I don't know what I am doing, so I will pretend I am at reddit.  I solved this problem with a simple solution, of adding `servername.conf`, but then it didn't work again, backed up by purging and reloading, but I do not have enough reputation to say this.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds a bit like some apache binaries might be missing.

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2*
```

that will remove all apache2 packages, then

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

As long as there are no errors through any of that then that should be fine. If you want to check apache is listening

```
sudo netstat -anop | grep apache
```

You should see apache listening on port 80. You can also check the status of apache2 by doing

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Comment: Don't purge, just use the `--reinstall` option.

Comment: @muru that's an option also. Being that OP had tried a few things I felt it was wiser to purge everything and then just install apache2 (which obviously will install dependencies also) to make sure OP was starting from the right point with no other packages they don't actually need.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to setup all you need to do is run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

Once it is done open your browser and type `localhost` in the address bar.

Comment: perhaps this works, but I already installed apache2, and localhost is not displaying Apache default page ("it works")

Comment: Pls just try reinstalling it.

Comment: its not responding to sudo service apache2 restart, I don't know how to "reinstall" it.  I just installed it tonight, although I had it installed in the past...

Comment: Just rerun the command

Comment: sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql

Comment: well, I still don't want to install a whole LAMP stack with one command, but re-installing apache2 worked, thanks

Comment: it was drinxy's answer that answered it.

Comment: @TrevorClarke apt-get install on a package which is already installed will update it at best (or do nothing at all if the package is already the latest version). It will not reinstall it. You either need to purge/remove it first or use the --reinstall option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update first , Run the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then reinstall Apache :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then it will work

Comment: Not a correct answer see the --reinstall command.